# update div with ajax onclick rails using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using acts as votable gem and implemented a voting system in the comments. Now I want the page to stop reloading when a user click on upvote or downvote link and update the vote counter. I'm tying to use this

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","URL_HERE",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

my _comment.html.erb

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
    <p>
            <div style="float: left; text-align: center; margin-right: 20px;" class="comment">
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <% if current_user.voted_for? comment %>
                        <%= link_to image_tag("updis.png", {:style => 'width: 30px'}), like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, :disabled => 'disabled' %><br />
                        <% if comment.likes.size > comment.dislikes.size %> 
                            +<%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                        <% elsif comment.likes.size < comment.dislikes.size %>
                            <%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                        <% else %>
                            <%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                        <% end %>
                        <%= link_to image_tag("downdis.png", {:style => 'width: 30px'}), dislike_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, :disabled => 'disabled' %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= link_to image_tag("upvote.png", {:style => 'width: 30px'}), like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put %><br />
                        <% if comment.likes.size > comment.dislikes.size %> 
                            +<%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                        <% elsif comment.likes.size < comment.dislikes.size %>
                            <%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                        <% else %>
                            <%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                        <% end %>
                        <%= link_to image_tag("downvote.png", {:style => 'width: 30px'}), dislike_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put %>
                    <% end %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= link_to image_tag("updis.png", {:style => 'width: 30px'}), like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, :disabled => 'disabled' %><br />
                    <% if comment.likes.size > comment.dislikes.size %> 
                        +<%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                    <% elsif comment.likes.size < comment.dislikes.size || comment.votes.size == 0 %>
                        <%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                    <% else %>
                        <%= comment.likes.size-comment.dislikes.size %><br />
                    <% end %>
                    <%= link_to image_tag("downdis.png", {:style => 'width: 30px'}), dislike_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put, :disabled => 'disabled' %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px;">
                <%= image_tag avatar_url(comment.user), class: 'profile-picture' %>
            </div>
            <strong>
                    <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at).capitalize %> আগে <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %> বলেছেন,
            </strong>
            <p>
                <%= comment.body %><br/><br />
            </p>
    </p>
    <hr />
<% end %>
```

I can't figure out what URL should I use in this line

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","URL_HERE",true);
```

can anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Have you got to use XHR or can you use `jQuery` (`$.ajax`) ?

Comment: anything that will work is fine for me...I even used rack pjax using railscasts video...but couldn't make it work

Comment: Ok thanks - let me write answer in a few minutes

Comment: Any special reason to not using Rails' built in ajax facilities? 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @scaryguy can you tell me what I have to use in place of appendTo to simply update the comments div with updated vote count? appendTo is adding the same comment with updated vote under the old comment...with both existing at the same time...

Comment: I tried replacewith which isn't doing anything, and also tried html which updates the div with only the updated comment removing other commens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `xhr` could easily be simplified by a much simpler implementation of `$.ajax` or the inbuilt rails [unobtrusive ajax](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html):

I'll explain how to get what you want using standard `$.ajax` (will show how it works):

---

**$.ajax**

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#vote_button").on("click", function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "your/vote/url",
        data: {data: "info"},
        success: function(data) { alert(data) }
        error: function(data) { alert(data) }
    });

});
```

To answer your question directly, the `url` you use has to be sent to the controller method which triggers the vote action

I've not got any experience with this particular gem, but I'll detail how you could create this functionality manually to give you an idea:

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pictures do 
    get :vote_up
    get :vote_down
end
```

---

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb
def vote_up
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    #create "up" vote here

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js #loads vote_up.js.erb
    end
end

def vote_down
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    #create "down" vote here

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js #loads vote_down.js.erb
    end
end
```

---

**Div**

You'll be able to update your rendered DIV by deploying code in the `.js.erb` file, or in your `ajax success` function

Comment: within this 1 hour I had some advancement on this issue...the parts you mentioned is already implemented....the thing I'm stuck on at this moment is I created two files 'upvote.js.erb' and 'downvote.js.erb' and I'm using '$('#comment').replacewith('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @comment) %>');' in them. its not working. if i use append it simply adds updated comment below the old comment...can you tell me what to use in place of append or replacewith?

Comment: to be precise tried to follow [this](http://reinteractive.net/posts/34-ruby-on-rails-3-2-blog-in-15-minutes-step-by-step-part-2) method of updating. They used append which is necessary for comment div. but what to use in place of append for simply refreshing or updating the full div? replacewith or html not giving expected results

Comment: Okay I would recommend using [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (which uses the [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)function in standard JS). Can you explain what "unexpected results" you're seeing from the `.html` command?

Comment: I already asked a question about it. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364900/update-specific-comment-using-javascript/21364969?noredirect=1#21364969